# SolrJ's UpdateRequest worth trying instead setting autoCommit in config?

Tags: java, performance, solr, commit, solrj

I am getting sometimes timeouts while inserting documents into Solr with SolrJ. Now I am searching for a solution and thought, maybe the autocommit could be a possible approach. I can set it directly in the **solrConfig.xml** or I can use **[CommitWithin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommitWithin)** in e.g. SorlJ.

Currently I am inserting documents, via [addBeans](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrServer.html#addBeans%28java.util.Collection%29), which is nice, because it's so comfortable.

The [UpdateRequest](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/UpdateRequest.html) only offers me the possibility to add SolrInputDocuments directly, so no beans. E.g. from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommitWithin:

```
   UpdateRequest req = new UpdateRequest();
   req.add(mySolrInputDocument);
   req.setCommitWithin(10000);
   req.process(server);
```

I don't know, if the general autoCommit is wise to set. It sounds like a 'hard' approach to me. And when I read the comment written in the solrconfig.xml

> Instead of enabling autoCommit, consider using "commitWithin" when adding documents.

I'm even more against this solution. Is the CommitWithin the smarter solution, which then of course means to write more code?

BTW: is it possible to add beans using the commitWithin feature?

Comment: Thanks, and do you know, if there is the possibility to add beans with the commitWithin feature?

Comment: But if you add via SolrJ and don't want to configure it in general in solrconfig.xml you have to write code to use this feature. Like e.g. with the UpdateRequest class. But I can't seee any addBeans functionality here. Just the possibility to add SolrInputDocuments.

Comment: Yes I was talking about config in solrconfig.xml.  I'm less familiar with the beans features; sorry. Actually I think I was confused about this whole thread - sorry if I wasted your time.